# NameError: global name 'PermissionError' is not defined (python 2.x)

Tags: python-3.x, permissions, python-2.x, nameerror

The following line:

```
except (IOError, PermissionError, FileNotFoundError) as e:
```

Gives the following error message when I run it with python 2.75:

```
NameError: global name 'PermissionError' is not defined
```

But everything runs fine with python 3.3.

Thoughts/suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This solved the issue for me for python 2.75 and 3.31:

```
from errno import EACCES, EPERM, ENOENT

def print_error_message(e, file_name):
    #PermissionError
    if e.errno==EPERM or e.errno==EACCES:
        print("PermissionError error({0}): {1} for:\n{2}".format(e.errno, e.strerror, file_name))
    #FileNotFoundError
    elif e.errno==ENOENT:
        print("FileNotFoundError error({0}): {1} as:\n{2}".format(e.errno, e.strerror, file_name))
    elif IOError:
        print("I/O error({0}): {1} as:\n{2}".format(e.errno, e.strerror, file_name))
    elif OSError:
        print("OS error({0}): {1} as:\n{2}".format(e.errno, e.strerror, file_name))

try:
...
except (IOError, OSError) as e:
    print_error_message(e,full_name)
    sys.exit()
except:
    print('Unexpected error:', sys.exc_info()[0])
    sys.exit()
```

Thoughts/comments/suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 17):

There was no `PermissionError` in Python 2.7, it was introduced in the Python 3.3 stream with [PEP 3151](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3151/). For a list of the 2.7 exceptions, see [here](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/exceptions.html).

PEP 3151 was an attempt to clean up the exception hierarchy for OS and I/O related exceptions.

I believe, before then, the equivalent would have been to catch `OSError` and check `errno` for `EPERM`, or `IOError` and check `errno` for `EACCES`.

You could always check if you're running under Python 3.3 or greater and, if not, create your own PermissionError. That'll never be *thrown* of course so you'll need to catch the two possibilities shown above as well.

Comment: I need for this code to work in both 2.7 and 3.3 on Win and Unix. Any ideas on how to make the code compatible for both? For example:<br> try: input = raw_input  <br>
except NameError: pass

Comment: I fiddled with it a bit and it works ok in both python versions when I change the except line to 'except (IOError, OSError) as e:'. Will have to do my own hierarchy inside the except handling so it will display the same messages on both python versions -- if you have ideas on how to implement this in another way (i.e. how to do your 2nd suggestion) I would really appreciate a code example.

Comment: @ofer, it's probably best to leave that to someone who's thought about it a great deal more than I: have a look at http://python3porting.com/toc.html. There's quite a bit in there about using `sys.version` for detection, even if you don't want to use the tools espoused in that document.